# Report errors manually from Rails to Sentry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry

In my ApiController  I have:

```
rescue_from Exception, with: :render_exception_error

  def render_exception_error(exception)
    raise exception if Rails.env.test?

    logger.error(exception)
    render json: { error: 'An error occurred' }, status: 500 unless performed?
  end
```

I want that method to also report the error to Sentry. 
Do you know if by doing the line that does `logger.error(...)` it automatically logs it in Sentry too?

Or do I have to manually do `Raven.capture_exception(exception)` or something like that? Will this be done in the background?

Comment: I'm not 100% since the docs doesn't look clear enough to me. First you have the `rails_report_rescued_exceptions` config option, but it's not clear if it only applies to middleware's rescues. I would just try it and if it does not report the exception then do `Raven.capture_exception(exception)`. There's also an `asnyc` config to report exceptions on the background https://docs.sentry.io/clients/ruby/config/

Comment: That is thankful, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit 2022

Raven is deprecated since a few months now and you should use the new Sentry gem.

To answer the question, which is *Report errors manually from Rails to Sentry*, you can check the documentation here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/guides/rails/usage/

TL;DR you can capture exception with

```rb
Sentry.capture_exception(exception)
```

Or you can capture a message with

```rb
Sentry.capture_message('Something went wrong')
```